# Check if message is number

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    counter = 1
    if message.channel.id == 895739649425825803 and not message.author.bot:
        if message.content == str(counter):
            await message.add_reaction("✅")
            counter += 1
            print(counter)
        else:
            # Here I want to check if message.content is a number.
            await message.add_reaction("❌")
            counter = 1
```

I want to create a game in a text channel. counter starts with 1 and the users have to count. If it's not right the counter resets to 1. But the bot also resets if someone sends a message which is not a number. How can I check if it's a number?

Comment: ``try`` and ``except``?

Comment: ``except ValueError`` to be more precise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `try-except` to change `message.content` to `int`

if `message.content` cant convert to `int` counter will be set as `1`

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    counter = 1
    if message.channel.id == 895739649425825803 and not message.author.bot:
        if message.content == str(counter):
            await message.add_reaction("✅")
            counter += 1
            print(counter)
        else:
            # Here I want to check if message.content is a number.
            try:
                  counter = int(message.counter)
            except ValueError:
                  counter = 1 
            await message.add_reaction("❌")
```

Comment: @GeorgiKoynov If you found this answer helpful and is satisfied with the answer and do believe this is the best answer for your question, you can mark it as accepted, click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in :)